# How to get the value via Linux command 'grep'

Tags: linux, docker, command-line

I want to get some specific information with docker api.
In this case,
I want to get the `IMAGE ID` that correspond to `<none>` of `REPOSITORY` with command `docker images`

```sh
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              ebeb5aebbeef        5 minutes ago       479MB
build-embed         latest              80636e4726f8        10 minutes ago      479MB
<none>              <none>              a2abf2e07bc3        About an hour ago   1.38GB
ubuntu              18.04               4e5021d210f6        5 weeks ago         64.2MB
```

I tried the command as below:

```sh
$ docker images | grep `<none>'
```

And get results:

```sh
<none>              <none>              ebeb5aebbeef        2 minutes ago       479MB
<none>              <none>              a2abf2e07bc3        58 minutes ago      1.38GB
```

How can I just only get the `IMAGE ID`? (like `ebeb5aebbeef a2abf2e07bc3`)

The purpose of this question is that I want to remove `<none>` images with docker api, like `docker rmi $(docker images | grep <none>`

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `awk` to get just the third field of the matching lines.

```
docker images | awk '$1 == "<none>" { print $3 }'
```

Don't use `grep '<none>'` since that can match in fields other than the `REPOSITORY`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think `awk` is really useful for developing in Linux

Answer (score 3):

Use [--filter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filtering) option with `-q` option, instead of listing all images and filtering them using `grep`

```
docker images -f "dangling=true" -q
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`docker images` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/) has a couple of options to do this more directly, without trying to parse apart its output.

[`docker images -f`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filtering) can filter the list of images presented on a minimal set of conditions.  One of those conditions is "dangling", which is exactly those images with `<none>` labels.  This can replace your `grep` command.

`docker images -q` prints out only the image IDs and not the rest of the line.  This can replace the `awk` command from [@Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61476433/10008173).

This would leave you with

```
docker images -f dangling=true -q
```

to print out the image IDs of `<none>` images, which is what you're after; and thereby

```
docker images -f dangling=true -q | xargs docker rmi
```

to remove them.

Also consider [`docker system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) which will remove dangling images, and also stopped containers and unused networks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm rookie of docker. Your detailed comment really help me understand docker.